# Changing margins on defined pages

Tags: margins

We all know that by adding:

```
\usepackage[left=...,right=...]{geometry}
```

changes the margins of the entire document. However, is there a way to modify the margins on the pages I'd want?

Comment: With the `geometry` package you can use `\newgeometry{<new settings>}` and then `\restoregeometry` to restore the initial settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package you can use

```
\newgeometry{<new settings>}
```

and then

```
\restoregeometry
```

to restore the initial settings. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,hmargin=3cm,vmargin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}
\newgeometry{margin=1cm}
\mbox{}
\restoregeometry
\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

[image]